# How can I test if a $cookie was set in an AngularJS service?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, cookies, karma-runner

My service is:

```
myApp.service('userService', [
  '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$state', '$cookies', '$base64', function($http, $q, $rootScope, $state, $cookies, $base64) {
    var user;
    user = {};

    this.logout = function() {
      user = {};
      delete $cookies.userAccessKey;
      return $state.transitionTo('login');
    };
  }
]);
```

I want to write a unit test to make sure that the `$cookies.userAccessKey` was deleted. How can I do this? While I'm at it, how can I ensure that `user` was set to empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if user is null, just add a public getter or checker :

```
myApp.service('userService', [
  '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$state', '$cookies', '$base64', function($http, $q, $rootScope, $state, $cookies, $base64) {
    var user;
    this.user = {}; // or a method this.isLoggedIn() for more security

    this.logout = function() {
      this.user = {};
      delete $cookies.userAccessKey;
      return $state.transitionTo('login');
    };
  }
]);
```

Then, in your tests :

```
describe('logout', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        userService.login(); //relog before each test
    });

    it('should remove the userAccessKey from cookie', function() {
        userService.logout();

        inject(function($cookies) {
          expect(cookies.userAccessKey).toBeUndefined();
        });
    });

    it('should reset user object', function() {
        userService.logout();

        expect(userService.user).toEqual({});
        });
    });
});
```